# Customize slick code generator

Tags: scala, slick

If I have

```
abstract class RichTable[T](tableTag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tableTag, name) {
   val tenantId: Column[Int] = column[Int]("tenant_id")
}
```

And slick generated Table class as follow

```
 class Dashboard(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[DashboardRow](_tableTag, "dashboard") {
```

I want to customize slick code generator to instead generate

```
class Dashboard(_tableTag: Tag) extends RichTable[DashboardRow](_tableTag, "dashboard") {
 ...
 override val tenantId: Column[Int] = column[Int]("tenant_id") //note override keyword
}
```

Is this possible to customize slick code generator particular for this case? Note: `extends RichTable` need to be applied selectively (a list of table classes vs every generated class).

Comment: Why not provide implicit conversion toRich[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q) instead of modifying the generator?

Comment: @cvogt : you're right override isn't required in there. any idea on customizing to be able to extend `RichTable` for a select list of tables?

Answer (score 0):

For RichTable you need to override def code of Table.

See

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/slick-codegen/src/main/scala/scala/slick/codegen/AbstractSourceCodeGenerator.scala#L128