# Enrich type with implicit

Tags: scala

Following my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977077/customize-slick-code-generator)(and one of the comments in there) I am trying to enrich classes (that extend `Table` )(from Slick) and add

`val tenantId: Column[Int] = column[Int]("tenant_id")`

I have got

```
class RichT[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q) {
  implicit def toRich= {
    val tenantId: Column[Int] = t.column[Int]("tenant_id")
  }
}
```

and

```
 implicit def table2RichTable[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q) = new RichT[T, Q](t)
```

while trying to write a generic function like follow it's still not able to find `tenantId` for the passed `T`(fails at compile time) telling me implicit conversion isn't working. I must be missing something silly in the implicit?

```
def selectById[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q, e: TableQuery[Q], id: Int)(implicit s: Session) = {
  e.filter(_.tenantId === id)
}
```

Update:

```
object RichTable {
  implicit class RichT[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q) {
    val tenantId: Column[Int] = t.column[Int]("tenant_id")
  }
}
```

`import RithTable._`

```
def selectById[T, Q <: Table[T]](t: Q, e: TableQuery[Q], id: Int)(implicit s: Session) = {
    e.filter(_.tenantId === id)
}
```

error `value tenantId is not a member of type parameter Q.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should just:

```
implicit class RichT[Q <: Table[_]](t: Q) {
  val tenantId: Column[Int] = t.column[Int]("tenant_id") 
}
```

Comment: Issue appears to the in the implicit. it's not able to fine `tenantId` property and fails on `e.filter(_.tenantId === id)` complaining value tenantId is not a member of type parameter Q.

Comment: of course it's not - because you have defined unnecessary implicit def toRich inside RichT instead of just `val tenantId = ...`. So you've added `toRich` instead of `tenantId` to the Q.

Comment: see Update section in the question. I don't have implicit def anymore when I get that compile error.